# MS SQL query slow because of bad plan or fragmented indexes

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, fragmentation, maintenance-plan

I have a stored procedure which usually runs pretty quickly (hardly a few seconds), but then there are odd days where the same proc with the same parameters takes minutes to execute. But if I defrag the indexes at this point, it starts running within seconds again.

Could this be because of bad execution plan or fragmented indexes?

If so, Is there a way I can make this procedure NOT dependant on execution plans or fragmented indexes?

Thanks in advance,
Joseph

Comment: You should try to execute it with recompile. You should also include your procedure.

Comment: Thanks. let me give that a try.

Comment: Could please give more details about this SP? Any code, piece of code, algorithms, parameters might give more hints...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, depending on your SP, the solution might be throught these options:

1/ `WITH RECOMPILE` could save your day. This increases the total execution time, by recompiling the SP, but it assures you'll have the best execution plan.

2/ `KEEPFIXED PLAN` could be also an option.

3/ It worths to give a try with `OPTIMIZE FOR` in case you have a set of parameters that are "representative" from statistics point of view.

4/ Monitor the level of fragmentation on involved tables and indexes. Check if there are statements that heavily updates the tables used by your SP. If yes, [update statistics](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/when-update-statistics-flag-2371) (`UPDATE STATISTICS <tablename>;`)

5/ Parameter sniffing could be also a root cause.

You can go further into details and see a [list of causes of recompilations](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/recompilation/causes-of-recompilations).

Comment: Thanks Mihai, I will explore these options further.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.  SQL Server relies on execution plans and indexes to perform well.

Longer answer: Maybe.  If your performance improves immediately after defragging your indexes, then my first question would be: which indexes, and why are they fragmenting?  Are you clustering on a uniqueidentifier?  Are your statistics up-to-date?  What's the execution plan look like?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a newbie.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to figure it out?